# Kotlin function required Nothing but defined as a different type

Tags: android, generics, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-extension

I've defined a class like so

```
abstract class MvpViewHolder<P>(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) where P : BasePresenter<out Any?, out Any?> {
    protected var presenter: P? = null

    fun bindPresenter(presenter: P): Unit {
        this.presenter = presenter
        presenter.bindView(itemView)
    }
}
```

where `presenter.bindView(itemView)` gives me an error stating `Type mismatch, required: Nothing, found: View!`. I've defined the `bindView` inside the `presenter` class like so

```
abstract class BasePresenter<M, V> {
     var view: WeakReference<V>? = null
     var model: M? = null

     fun bindView(view: V) {
        this.view = WeakReference(view)
    }
}
```

It is taking in a value of `view: V`.

I've tried defining my extension of `BasePresenter<out Any?, out Any?>` using the star syntaxt `BasePresenter<*,*>` but I get the same error. I've also tried using just simply `BasePresenter<Any?, Any?>` which fixes the direct problem, but then anything that is extending `P: BasePresenter<Any?, Any?>` Gives an error saying that it was expecting P, but got `BasePresenter<Any?, Any?>`

Here is an example where that happens within my code

```
abstract class MvpRecyclerListAdapter<M, P : BasePresenter<Any?, Any?>, VH : MvpViewHolder<P>> : MvpRecyclerAdapter<M, P, VH>() {...}
```

On this line, I would get the error mentioned above on the part the extends `MvpRecyclerAdapter<M, P, VH>`

I just can't seem to get around this. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've declared **out** for generic parameter **V** at `BasePresenter<out Any?, out Any?>`, so `presenter.bindView` must not take input parameters.

Solution: change declaration to `BasePresenter<out Any?, View?>`.

Check [official doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#declaration-site-variance) for more infomation.

Comment: it'll still give me the error on this line 

`abstract class MvpRecyclerListAdapter<M, P : BasePresenter<Any?, View?>, VH : MvpViewHolder<P>> : MvpRecyclerAdapter<M, P, VH>() {...}`

stating that, specifically for `P` that it `expects `P` but found BasePresenter<M,VH>

Comment: @Rafa shouldn't usages of `P` in your generics be `P : BasePresenter<Any?, View?>` everywhere .. I mean generics are good, but you've gone to town with them here ...

Comment: You're right. and yea, I'm starting an app using MVP and I'm trying to convert this code over to Kotlin https://github.com/remind101/android-arch-sample/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/remind101/archexample  

It's proven to be pretty difficult converting the generic signatures to Kotlin

Comment: @Rafa, did you resolve these issues above, I'm trying convert the same code over to Kotlin